# Python time.time accept self args

Tags: python

According to the following snippet:

```py
import time

def custom_time():
    return time.time()

class TimeWrapper:
    builtin_time = time.time
    def print_builtin(self):
        print(self.builtin_time())

    custom_time = custom_time
    def print_custom(self):
        print(self.custom_time())

wrapper = TimeWrapper()

wrapper.print_builtin()
# 1660163626.7973292
wrapper.print_custom()
# TypeError: custom_time() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
time.time(wrapper)
# TypeError: time.time() takes no arguments (1 given)
custom_time(wrapper)
# TypeError: custom_time() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

I do not understand why `wrapper.print_builtin()` is working.
Is it not supposed to be the equivalent of `time.time(wrapper)`?

Is there a connection with the `unused` argument from [C implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Modules/timemodule.c#L86) ?
If it is not the case, I'm still interested in this unused variable.

Comment: A deep dive on descriptors is at https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`time.time` has type `builtin_function_or_method`, not `function`. Such objects do not implement the descriptor protocol:

```
>>> time.time.__get__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__get__'
```

so `self.builtin_time` simply returns `time.time`, not a `method` object that implicitly passes `self` as the first argument to `time.time`.

That is, `self.builtin_time()` is exactly the same as `time.time()`, not `time.time(self)`.

Comment: I think you have it backwards. `custom_time = custom_time` creates a method object, but the function accepts no arguments. The errors you are describing are not what OP is seeing.

Comment: I'm explaining why `time.time` does not receive the instance as an argument when calling `print_builtin`. Both `builtin_time` and `custom_time` are simple classes attributes; the difference is that `custom_time` *is* an instance of `function`, which implements the descriptor protocol.

Comment: `print_custom` fails because  `custom_time` was not defined with a parameter to accept the argument that `self.custom_time` (the bound method of type `method`) will try to pass to it.

Comment: super clear! thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting side-effect of how methods really work. A method is just a function in a class dictionary. For example:

```
class A:
   def b(self):
       print("b")

def c(self):
    print("c")

A.c = c
a = A()
```

The reason that both `b` and `c` are equally methods of `A` is that they are descriptors. When you access a descriptor from an instance of a class using dot notation, as in `a.b` or `a.c`, python will perform the following binding: `type(a).b.__get__(a)`. The bound method is a callable that automatically passes `self` to the underlying function. Whether you define a method in the class or outside a class and add it to the class dictionary by other means, it will behave the same.

The behavior of `c` in the example above is exactly the same as `custom_time` in your example. By setting `custom_time = custom_time` in the class body, you are creating a method just as if you had placed `def custom_time():` in the class body. When you call the subsequently bound method as `self.custom_time()`, the bound method passes instance `self` as the first argument, even though the function accepts no arguments. Hence your error.